# Authorize just one spreadsheet in the Google Spreadsheet API

Tags: google-sheets, google-oauth, google-sheets-api

I'm working on some .Net code to collect some data on a server and put it in a Google Spreadsheet. The job needs to run once a day, clear out the sheet and repopulate it. I have all that working, but I can't get the authorization right. I can do it with my personal Google credentials, and I can get it to work with OAUTH by allowing the app to manipulate all my spreadsheets using the https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds scope. But, what I really want to do is allow my script to read and write just one sheet. Is that possible, and how would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You are using very old scopes. Look at the drive.file scope

https://developers.google.com/drive/web/scopes

Comment: I'm not sure if the drive.file scope makes any sense here. It seems to be for Apps that run inside of the Google Drive platform. I'm trying to write code that runs on an independent box and manipulates a specific spreadsheet as a scheduled task. I'm not creating a Google Drive App, although that may be a possibility if I need to.

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible using the spreadsheets API. That api is very old and doesnt have a scope for indivdual files.
it might be possible by creating a spreadsheet using the drive API by uploading a CSV with conversion, but you will need permission to create new drive files and that also means permission to the entire drive.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: Create a new google account and share the spreadsheet with it. Do the OAuth using the new account.

@Zig Mandel is right - the API (Gdata style) wants access to all spreadsheets. But you can workaround the problem using a new account.